# Problems with calculating the limit $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x{\lvert \sin(t)\rvert dt}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, absolute-value, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I wanted to check whether theorem below is true, for some simple case:
$$\lvert\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)\rvert=\infty \Rightarrow \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x{\lvert \sin(f(t))\rvert\, dt}=\frac{2}{\pi}$$
And I let $f(x)=x$
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x{\lvert \sin(f(t))\rvert\, dt}=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\int_0^x{\lvert \sin(t)\rvert\, dt}}{x}$$
To calculate this limit we should be able to use L'Hospital's rule.
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\int_0^x{\lvert \sin(t)\rvert \,dt}}{x}=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x{\lvert \sin(t)\rvert\, dt}=\lim_{x\to \infty} \lvert \sin(x)\rvert$$
But this limit does not exist.

 However I managed to calculate this limit in other way, firstly evaluating the integral.
$$\int_0^x{\lvert \sin(t)\rvert\, dt}=\int_0^{\{\frac{x}{\pi}\}\pi}\lvert\sin(t)\rvert\,dt+\int_0^{\lfloor \frac{x}{\pi} \rfloor\pi}\lvert \sin(t)\rvert\, dt=\int_0^{\{\frac{x}{\pi}\}\pi} \sin(t)\, dt+\Bigl\lfloor\frac{x}{\pi}\Bigr\rfloor\int_0^{ {\pi} } \sin(t)\,dt= $$
$$=1-\cos(\{\frac{x}{\pi}\}\pi)+2\lfloor\frac{x}{\pi} \rfloor,$$
where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$

Applying this formula to the limit we get:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\int_0^x{\lvert \sin(t)\rvert\, dt}}{x}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1-\cos(\{\frac{x}{\pi}\}\pi)+2\bigl\lfloor\frac{x}{\pi} \bigr\rfloor}{x}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{2\bigl\lfloor\frac{x}{\pi} \bigr\rfloor}{x}=2 \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{x}\Bigl(\frac{x}{\pi}-\Bigl\{\frac{x}{\pi}\Bigr\}\Bigr)=\frac{2}{\pi}-\lim_{x \to\infty}{\frac{1}{x}\Bigl\{\frac{x}{\pi}\Bigr\}}=\frac{2}{\pi}$$
Which is supposed result. It seems that the second result is proper, but then the question is: **why can't we apply L'Hospital's rule to this limit?**

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Which limit are you talking about ?

Comment: The assumption in the L'Hopital's rule is that the limit $\lim\frac{F'}{G'}$ exists. In your case it doesn't, as you right pointed out :]

Comment: In order to apply L'Hopital when you use the rule the resulting limit should exist. In your case it does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [L'Hospital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule), 
$$ \lim_{x\to c}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} $$
is supposed to exist. But in your problem, it doesn't exist. So you can't use this rule for this problem.